# Всем привет! Можно ли как-то собирать из готовой таблицы MySQL запросы на её создание?

Tags: php, mysqli, резервное-копирование

Например `$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$file' FROM results");` с помощью этой строчки я собираю всю информацию из таблицы и записываю её в .sql файл, но смысл от того что я сохраняю все это в .sql уходит, тк тем же самым `mysqli_multi_query($link, $query);` я не поимею ничего с данного файла. Как бы можно было формировать .sql файл со всеми запросами собирая информацию из заданной мной таблицы? Это уже получается бекап-файл с помощью которого потом я бы мог все откатить например при удалении данной таблицы. Может есть какие-либо готовые скрипты? Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: обычно для бекапа настраивают крон, который запускает команду `mysqldump`

Comment: [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) - советую прочитать

Comment: Хорошо, почитаю)